# How to implement a custom action to run code with access to the current item columns

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, custom-actions

I am using sp2013. I have a custom list which is using a custom content type. I would like to implement some link or button which is running some code. First you will need to select a listitem. In this code I would like to get the listitem and do some logic and update a column in this list item.

What is the best method to do this? Custom action or visual studio workflow?

And is it possible to create a custom action in sharepoint designer, and set my url to some custom c# asp.net page (test.aspx). And in this url I would like to add querystring with list id and listitem id.